# Formatting a \paragraph to look like a \section

Tags: formatting, sectioning, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

I'm writing a document that contains a rather deep tree of nested lists, and was wondering if how I would go about reformatting the `\paragraph` macro to format the text contained within it as a `\section`, specifically by separating the title from the body and placing it above the body. I've encountered the `titlesec` package but I'm confused as to how to use it since it seems to be used very little so there are very few examples to follow.

---

**Update 1**: I'm using the article document class.

Comment: Which document class are you using? `\paragraph` and `\section` are macros of the class (or a package) and their implementation can be different depending on the class.

Comment: Iirc, the *LaTeX Companion* has a section dedicated to `titlesec` (my copy is a few thousand kilometers away, so I can’t check).

Comment: I'm using the article documentclass. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pages 26-27 of the titlesec documentation show "how [the] sectioning commands of the standard classes could be defined" using titlesec commands. Take the definition of `\paragraph` and change the optional "format" argument of `\titleformat` from `runin` to `hang` (or drop it entirely).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{A paragraph}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

EDIT: To make a `\paragraph` look exactly like a `\section` in the article class, use

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
```

Answer (score 3):

[This FAQ answer](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-subsubsub) talks about defining a `\subsubsubsection`, if that is what you are looking for, and recommends either titlesec or reading the latex sources to understand the usage of `\@startsection`.

I get the impression that titlesec is used quite a bit, mostly in professional book production so you are unlikely to see many worked examples, beyond the ones in the titlesec manual.